# How to clean / reduce properties of a model instance to reduce json size?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pusher

I have a process where some models are updated and after that I send the updated object to pusher for real time tracking through an control board but the object has several other objects as relationships so the size of the serialized object exceed the pusher limit size for a message so my question is how can I delete some properties of the related objects?

I already tried pluck function but I don't know how to use on neastead objects

```html
$vehicleEntry = VehicleEntry::with('vehicle')->find($request->entryId);
// I need just the id and plate of the object
$vehicleEntry->pluck('vehicle.id', 'vehicle.plate');
```

but it gets error

{id: 1, vehicle: {id: 2, plate: 'JIS575'}, created_at: '2019-07-11'}

Comment: Does it work if you do `$vehicleEntry->vehicle->pluck('id', 'plate');`? I forget if `pluck()` handles nested properties with `.` syntax or if you need to access the intermediate object first.

Answer (score 3):

One way I personally prefer is to make use of [API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources). This way you always have full control over the data that is being returned.

Example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class VehicleEntryResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => (int) $this->resource->id,
            // Watch out with this. Make sure the vehicle relation is loaded.
            // Otherwise it will always add this execute another query for
            // every vehicle entry you send to this class, would be bad when
            // you want to send multiple. You could also use
            // $this->whenLoaded('vehicle'), however this needs another
            // resource.
            'vehicle' => [
                'id' => (int) $this->resource->vehicle->id,
                'plate' => $this->resource->vehicle->plate,
            ],
            'created_at' => $this->resource->created_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you can call this anywhere you want:

```php
new VehicleEntryResource($vehicleEntry);
```

Not sure if Pusher messages works as nice as the `JsonResponse` you generally would return in your controller. When returning it in a response it would convert them to arrays automatically. But you could also do the following to get the array representation:

```php
(new VehicleEntryResource($vehicleEntry))->toArray(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is to add a `$hidden` property to your model and give it an array of strings that are property names you'd like to hide from json output:

```
protected $hidden = [
    'hide', 
    'these', 
    'attributes', 
    'from', 
    'json'
];
```

When your object is converted to json it will automatically prevent any attributes listed in the `$hidden` array from showing up.

See the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json